# How does HBase calculate the flush size?

Tags: hbase

I am trying to better understand memstore flush algorithm in HBase.

I have a simple (snappy-compressed) table with 1 column family and I have configured HBase as follows (I have a couple of regions on this region server):

- hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size: 128 mib
- Java Heap Size of HBase RegionServer in Bytes: 10 Gib
- hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit: 0.4
- hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size.lower.limit: 0.95

Based on the logs it seems like flushes are happening at 70mb mark what i see in the logs repeatedly is something similar to this

`DefaultStoreFlusher    Flushed memstore data size=68.14 MB at sequenceid=12561`

Why not 128 mb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data size is sum of cell data alone (key bytes + value bytes). This is the actual data that will be flushed to Hfile.
But heap usage for the same data is usually more. Along with cell's data, it includes the metadata and index. Flush happens when heap size reaches hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size. Log might call that out.

Comment: ya it should be freed up if the data is flushed and no recent read req has come in for it

Comment: So is it safe to say we should not restart the hbase process worrying about memory

Answer (score 0):

now `hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit` is deprecated by `hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size`

if the size of **one** memstore reaches `hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size` then **all** memstores in the region will be flushed(even those are less than 128 mb) also there is a region server setting that trigger flushing that adjusted by `hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size` and `hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size.lower.limit`, if the sum of all memstore sizes in a region server exceed
`Heap * hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size.lower.limit *   hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size`
then all memstores in the region will be flushed